# How to create values for map in dagger

Tags: java, dagger

In my nano project, I decided to replace big nasty switch statement with map of commands. Now I'm in the process of tiding up my code and i want to create provider which provides me populated map.

I wonder, what will be best practice for that. Initially i was thinking about something like this:

```
@Provides 
ActionResolver provideActionResolver(Dependency dep1,Dependency dep2) {
  Map<SomeEnum,Action> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put(SomeEnum.A1,new Action1(dep1);
  map.put(SomeEnum.A2,new Action2(dep2);
  return new ActionResolver(map);
}
```

I wonder is it right way to go, and what is the best practice for this.

Comment: you're probably looking for [**Map Multibindings**](http://google.github.io/dagger/multibindings.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [**Map Multibindings**](http://google.github.io/dagger/multibindings.html), if I'm correct, you could do the following:

```
@MapKey
@interface SomeEnumKey {
    SomeEnum value();
}

@Provides 
@IntoMap
@SomeEnumKey(SomeEnum.A1)
Action action1(@Named("dep1") Dependency dep1) {
    return new Action1(dep1);
}

@Provides 
@IntoMap
@SomeEnumKey(SomeEnum.A2)
Action action2(@Named("dep2") Dependency dep2) {
    return new Action2(dep2);
}

@Provides 
ActionResolver provideActionResolver(Map<SomeEnum, Action> actions) {
    return new ActionResolver(actions);
}
```

Comment: +1, but if you don't know you're going to need every `Action` instance in the Map, you may prefer a `Map<SomeEnum, Provider<Action>>` to save on some creation/collection costs.